# How to give Edit access to a user to the records that are not owned by him

Tags: profile, permissions, owd

I have a custom object with OWD as private. Now I have a requirement where a user has should be able to EDIT records that are not owned by him But should not be able to delete them. I tried creating a permission set. But a permission set is working only if i give him Modify all access and this includes Delete also (it is not what i wanted). When i un-check Delete which will automatically un-check modify all and at the same time the user will have edit access only to the records he own but not all.

How do i address this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write Sharing rule and give the user **Read/Write** access to the record.

You should not give 'Modify All' permission to the user.

In the user's Profile, Give Read and Edit permission for that Custom Object, if you need all user's of that profile will have Edit access.

Otherwise, for a specific user, if you want to give Edit permission then use permission set and assign permission set to that user.

Suggest you to go through [Sharing architecture](http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/5/en-us/sfdc/pdf/sharing_architecture.pdf)

[image: Sharing architecture]

Comment: I tried sharing rule too. But still seeing insufficient privileges error only.

Comment: First you need to give Edit permission to that user, then sharing rule will come into play. If a user doesn't have Edit permission at Object level then sharing a record with Read/Write access will not serve the purpose

Comment: OWD is private. so you need to write sharing rule for that along with permission set assignment with EDIT access

Comment: Still not working. This is how i set up a user sharing rule. step-1 name, step-2 Based on Criteria, step-3 Nickname contains ********** , step-4: selected the above user role, step-5 read/write.

Comment: Create a public group and add user into a public group. finally select the public group in sharing rule definition

Comment: Still getting the same error. OWD=private then created a permission set with create, Read, Edit, View all permissions. Created a public group with this user and then added a sharing rule with this public group but no luck. Do i need to change Anything?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59191/discussion-between-santanu-boral-and-avinash-babu).